# two nics on ubuntu server cannot reach outside

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-12.04

I have two Nics on server:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.137.66.69
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8


auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.137.15.20
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.137.15.1
```

-10.137.15.X is where we want our web server/SSH/FTP to respond. We want it separate from the 10.137.66.x for security. No access to the .66 or eth0

-10.137.66.x is our corp network that we will use to access the server while in the network.

We have mysql/apache/ssh etc all listening on all interfaces.

How its behaving:

WHILE ON CORP NET: I have access to our site, SSH and etc. The server can ping 8.8.8.8.
WHEN OUTSIDE NETWORK: I cannot access any thing.

If I run: 
*sudo route add default gw 10.137.15.1 eth1* I get access from the outside & inside. HOWEVER, now the server itself cannot ping/access/resolv to the outside. Which is a problem for PHP and other web services on the server.

Can someone give me direction or show an proper config for what I am wanting pretty please?

Answer (score 0):

since you use google's DNS server, you need to either allow the DNS requests to go through the 10.137.15.1 gateway (I guess they are filtered), or to add a more specific route to 8.8.8.8 via the gateway in the 10.137.66.0/24 network.

If the latter is what you need, just add the following line to your eth0 config :

```
post-up /sbin/ip route add 8.8.8.8/32 via 10.137.66.1
```

where 10.137.66.1 is the gateway. You could also use the route command if you like.